# Can I change between the two usages of Chrome Switch Users? CTRL-SHIFT-M

Tags: google-chrome

I just provisioned a new machine, and inside Google Chrome setup the same two users as on my old machine.

- Both of these are Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit.
- Both are running the same Version of Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m

But they have different "switch user" UI's. On my old machine which has been setup for about a year, when I press CTRL-SHIFT-M - I get a nice drop down menu of two users on the very top left of the Chrome Browswer. Down Arrow + Enter, either launches that new user, or switches to it, if it's already running.

In the new machine, CTRL-SHIFT-M, Launched a pull down menu on the top right, under a label (that is also new). From here I have to Down Arrow to select "switch user" then a UI pops up, showing the two users, then I have to Arrow to the new user and press enter. It's a much longer process to switch users.

Is there a way to restore the older / faster approach to switching users?

There must be, as I'm using the same builds on two machines with two different experiences.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after months of painful extra keystrokes, I ran across this solution.

[chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags) -> then CTRL+F (search in page) for "profile management" There are 4 nodes. Change the forth question to Disabled. This will bring back the CTRL+SHIFT+M -> Down Arrow Quick Selection.

This is Soooo much faster than the new fancy popup "Switch User" dialog.

[image: Chrome Flags Screen Capture]

Comment: not working at this moment ... see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491038

Comment: hurray, fixed in v. 55.0.2883.75